# View code changes without restarting the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, dnx

We're using Visual Studio Code and DNX as follows.

Command Line to Start Web Server

```
dnx . web
```

project.json > commands

```
"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting 
       --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener 
       --server.urls http://localhost:5001"
```

Note that we added carriage returns for readability.

When we change a `*.cshtml` and refresh the browser, the changes show up in the browser. This is good.

When we change a `*.cs` and refresh the browser, the changes do not show up in the browser. We expected that they would. To see the changes, we need to stop the web server (with `Ctrl + C` in the command line) and then start it again with `dnx . web`.

This isn't the end of the world; that said, I thought one of the features of ASP.NET 5 was the ability to refresh without recompiling etc.

How can we change `*.cs` code and refresh the browser to see the changes without having to restart the DNX web server?

We have tried running `dnx --watch . web` with the problem that, if we change a `*.cs` file, then the web server stops and we must restart it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. You can use something like [gulp-aspnet-k](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/gulp-aspnet-k) to automate this process. More detailed info available here: [Building and Running Your ASP.NET vNext Application with Gulp](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/building-and-running-your-asp-net-vnext-application-with-gulp).

Note that this gulp integration unfortunately [only works on Windows now](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/gulp-aspnet-k/issues/7) but all it does is to [watch the dnx process and restart it again](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/gulp-aspnet-k/blob/54a0ad37b268a54e150de7b00d5d1f5a03e8890d/index.js#L32).

Comment: The npm package has been renamed to `gulp-aspnet-dnx` (as one would expect).  But it isn't needed.  On windows just run this powershell: `for(;;) { Write-Output "Starting..."; dnx --watch . web }`

Answer (score 5):

The change code on the fly feature works only when running **without debugging**. I assume you just press F5 (debug) from VS which actually attaches a debugger. Try without and it should work.

Long story short: in order to refresh the code behind, the server has to restart. When running from the command line, the server stops and never restarts - you have to handle that yourself, like @tugberk suggested - but when running from VS, tooling takes care of that for you.

Comment: there is dnx-watch for that. isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, we just published it yesterday

Answer (score 1):

There is a command you can use for this, called dnx-watch. It didn't exist when the original question was asked, but was added in beta 8 in September 2015. You install it using

dnu commands install Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher
You run it by simply passing to it the command you would have passed to dnx. So, replace

```
dnx web
```

with

```
dnx-watch web
```

You can learn more here: http://ardalis.com/get-started-with-dnx-watch

Comment: Is there a way to hot reload (like webpack does ) Here it's restarting the web process (when using dnx-watch web) but you still need to press F5 to see the changes

Comment: Not that I know of; FYI it's shifting to use dotnet-watch, here: https://github.com/aspnet/dotnet-watch

Comment: Thx, I found this project [NodeServices-Webpack](https://github.com/aspnet/NodeServices/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SpaServices/Webpack). I tried, but as it's in alpha I couldn't make it work so will wait a little till it's more stable