# Any way to run .net core web app without debug mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am developing a asp.net core web application in visual studio 2015 update 3.

Every time i have to check for the update in browser i have to either F5 the app which takes time or if i run "start without debugging" i get build error of unable to access "aspnet core identity dll" that is used by some process.

In asp.net  mvc app i could just build app and then check in browser without having to F5 or Ctrl F5 which takes time.

Is there any way i could just make changes in code then just build app and check in browser rather than to run in debug mode ?

Comment: I must be doing something HORRIBLY wrong because this question only has 892 views and I ALWAYS have this issue. With Ctrl+F5 it'll work 2-3 times max and then I get gateway issues and file locks.

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft created a "watch" tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch) that you can add to your `project.json` which enables you to start the backend code in "watch mode"...

1. Add `Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools` to the `tools` section of the `project.json` file.
2. Run `dotnet restore`.
3. Run with `dotnet watch run`
4. Check [the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch) above for further details

Then for your frontend code you can do as suggested by Michel Amorosa

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gulp to configure automatic change, 
someone explained it here : [View code changes without restarting the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30289023/view-code-changes-without-restarting-the-server)